# Is there a way to use adb to get an android app's appstate.bin without rooting the phone?

Tags: android, adb, backup

I want to inspect my opera browser's appstate.bin file. If I execute `adb backup com.opera.browser` the resulting backup.ab is empty after converting to tar format.

Comment: show what you have tried

Comment: I have - ```adb backup```

Answer (score 0):

I believe that the backup file is empty because in the Opera `AndroidManifest.xml` file the flag `allowBackup` is set to `false`.

As a workaround you can do the following:

1. decompile the apk using [apktool](https://ibotpeaches.github.io/Apktool/)
2. change the `AndroidManifest` and set `allowBackup=true`
3. rebuild the Opera apk using apktool
4. backup again and most likely the file size won't be empty